# How to access a String in a async function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

I have an async function inside of a stateful widget. Under the BuildContext, I have this function,

```
getChildren() async {
      final String numberOfChildren = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("children")
          .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: uid)
          .snapshots()
          .length
          .toString();
    }
```

How do I use the the `numberOfChildren` variable inside of a Text widget.

```
            Text(
                'Children: $numberOfChildren',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Color(0xff74828E),
                  fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
```

But it says that `numberOfChild`

[image]

How can I use this in a text widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("children")
          .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: uid)
          .snapshots(), // async work
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
       switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
         case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading....');
         default:
           if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
           else
          return Text(
                'Children: ${snapshot.data.docs.length}');
        }
      },
    )
```

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer to your question, thanks!

Comment: I will, but in 8 min, idk y there is a limit. I was going to

Comment: oh its 3 min, =)

Answer (score 1):

That's basics of OOP
You have to make numberOfChildren a variable of the class so you can use it on any function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variable numberOfChildren is local to that function. What you can do is make it global by declaring the variable right inside the class i.e

```
String numberOfChildren;
getChildren() async {
  numberOfChildren = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("children")
      .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: uid)
      .snapshots()
      .length
      .toString();
}
```